# adding images to a gridpane javafx

Tags: image, javafx, space, scrollpane, gridpane

I'm adding a list of images from a directory using an arraylist.When images are added,my ScrollPane gets crowded.How can I keep spacings between images ?

here's my code

```
File file = new File("D:\\SERVER\\Server Content\\Apps\\icons");
File[] filelist1 = file.listFiles();
ArrayList<File> filelist2 = new ArrayList<>();
hb = new HBox();

for (File file1 : filelist1) {
     filelist2.add(file1);
}

System.out.println(filelist2.size());
gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(50,50,50,50));
gridpane.setHgap(20);
gridpane.setVgap(20);

int imageCol = 0;
int imageRow = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < filelist2.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(filelist2.get(i).getName());
    image = new Image(filelist2.get(i).toURI().toString());
    pic = new ImageView();
    pic.setFitWidth(130);
    pic.setFitHeight(130);
    pic.setImage(image);
    hb.getChildren().add(pic);
    gridpane.add(pic, imageCol, imageRow );

    imageCol++;

    // To check if all the 4 images of a row are completed
    if(imageCol > 2){
      // Reset Column
      imageCol=0;
      // Next Row
      imageRow++;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Read the javadoc of gridpane. The "Optional Layout Constraints" part.

Comment: Can you post an image of the issue faced by you ?

Comment: It's that I'm low in my reputation I'm unable to upload a photo.Can I mail you instead?

Comment: i got very little experience with javascript try the .setMargin meathod example : 

image.setMargin(new Insets(2,2,2,2))

Comment: image.setMargin(new Insets(2,2,2,2)) has to be corrected as GridPane.setMargin(imageview, new Insets(2,2,2,2));

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HBox` and `VBox`.

Basically, they are like little containers where you store your stuff and you can add gaps into it!

```
HBox ab = new HBox(10); <--The 10 is adding space (Answer to your question)
```

If you want to add stuff into HBox, simply write

```
ab.getChildren().addAll(your content here);
```