# JavaFX: Inserting image into a GridPane

Tags: java, image, javafx, gridpane

Basically, I just want to insert an image into a cell within a gridpane.

```java
GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
gridpane.add(new Image("File:image/myfile.jpg"));
getChildren().addAll(gridpane);
```

Always tells me "Image is abstract, cannot be instantiated". Which I've Googled pretty extensively vaguely found that I have to use this as a BufferedImage or something? Not actually getting it though. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that you have the wrong import for `Image` (you probably have `java.awt.Image`). The import you need for a JavaFX image is

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image ;
```

You then need to wrap the image in an `ImageView`, and add the `ImageView` to the grid pane:

```
GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
Image image = new Image("File:image/myfile.jpg")
gridpane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));
```

Comment: This got me a little further(I did have the wrong import), but now it's telling me there's an error with that last line "no suitable method for add(ImageView)".

Is there another importI need to make ImageView work?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated it.

Comment: Awesome, that took care of it. It finally compiles. Now how can I assign that to a certain row/column? I already see that:

gridpane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image),1,1);

Doesn't work.

Comment: See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)

Comment: SetRowIndex and SetColumnIndex did the trick for me. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code ;)

```
image = new Image("File:image/myfile.jpg");
pic = new ImageView();
pic.setFitWidth(130);
pic.setFitHeight(130);
pic.setImage(image);
gridpane.add(pic);
```

[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374578/adding-images-to-a-gridpane-javafx)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
GridPane pane = new GridPane();
FileInputStream imageStream = new FileInputStream("us.gif");
Image image = new Image(imageStream);
pane.add(new ImageView(image), 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Image is an abstract class and thus cannot be instancied. You should use one of the class who extend Image, like BufferedImage

```java
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: This is a JavaFX question; this answer would be appropriate if the OP were asking about Swing/AWT images.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("picture.jpg")));
```